# What is the subject of "has enormous demands placed on his or her time"? What is the meaning of that clause in the context?

Tags: grammar, subjects

From [Fundamentals of Management](https://books.google.com/books?id=9DdBBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=%22faces%20increased%20complexities%20posed%20by%20globalization%22&source=bl&ots=AgxJmF2Vy-&sig=ACfU3U1MLr3q-Ny9460IEzJ7AGjcy0p7Ng&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNyvbv6vH4AhXYk4kEHdRPC7UQ6AF6BAgzEAI#v=onepage&q=%22faces%20increased%20complexities%20posed%20by%20globalization%22&f=false):

> The average executive works 60 hours a week; **has enormous demands placed on his or her time;** and faces increased complexities posed by globalization.

Comment: The subject of all three clauses is _the average executive_. The semicolons should be commas, and the rule of Conjunction Reduction has removed the repeated subjects in the last two clauses.

Comment: What is the meaning of the second clause in the context?

Comment: It's complaining about how many demands are placed on the average executive's time. All three clauses say the same thing -- executives work too much, and too hard, and they still don't solve the increasing problems. Poor executives. Don't you feel sorry for them?

Comment: "Demand placed on his time" mean?

Comment: In which sense "has" here been used?

Comment: _Has_ is an auxiliary verb and marks the Perfect construction; it has no meaning. _Placing a demand on one's time_ means demanding that one do something that takes time: "Get that report to me by Wednesday!".

Comment: Is "has placed enormous demand on his time=has enormous demand placed on his time"?

Comment: No. "Has placed demand" means the exec put the pressure on. "Demand placed" means the exec **received** that pressure (passively).

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of a question you asked earlier?

Comment: You should look up the noun "demands" in a dictionary.

Comment: @JohnLawler: the actual original sentence was considerably longer and had commas within the third clause, which is why the author used semicolons to separate the clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The average executive** is the subject. S/he:

- works 60 hours a week
- has enormous demands placed on his or her time
- faces increased complexities posed by globalization.

I would have used commas instead of semicolons because each of the three points doesn't have any punctuation and is not really that long or complex.

If the average executive works 60 hours a week, there's only a certain amount of work that can get done in that 60 hours. The meaning of:

> has enormous demands placed on his or her time

is that there are many people who expect the executive to accomplish certain things during those 60 hours, such has his or her boss, peers, subordinates and external parties such as customers and board members. The sum of those expectations is enormous compared to the amount of time the executive has to accomplish them.